# Swipe down modal only when at the top of FlatList

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist, react-native-gesture-handler

I am trying to clone TikTok comments modal (see gif below) where users should be able to scroll down to view more comments and once they scroll up and reach the top, they modal will be pulled down instead.

[image: TikTok Comments]

In my code, I enclosed the FlatList with PanGestureHandler. Currently, once the user reach the top of the comments and tried to swipe down, the modal does not move.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the scroll value and on the basis of this value, you can apply the scroll down condition. Use this in FlatList and set state accordingly.
Hopefully, this will help you a lot

```
 onMomentumScrollEnd={(event) => { 
      if(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y > 105){
        setselectedbutton(2)
      }else if(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y < 105){
        setselectedbutton(1)
      }
   }}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use  https://github.com/gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet, this repo provide a `BottomSheetFlatList` which is exactly what you need